# Reporting services: Total and percentages for each row

Tags: reporting-services

I want a result to look like this (converting from a solution in Excel to reporting services):

```
Campaigns      Success      Not Success      Total      Success %     Not sucess %
Campaign 1     1            4                5          20%           80%
Campaign 2     4            4                8          50%           50%
```

How do I accomplish this task? I can add the `Total` column, without any problems - but I don't know how to add the `Success %` and `Not success %` columns.

Comment: Are you using a table or a matrix for this?

Answer (score 3):

I think to add new columns you just need to right click and add a new column?

For the `"=Details"` field of the Success % column, right click and select "expression" to get to the expression editor. Then enter the following expression

```
=(Fields!Success.Value/Fields!Total.Value) * 100
```

For the Not success column do similar except your expression would be

```
=(Fields!NotSuccess.Value/Fields!Total.Value) * 100
```

(obviously the names of the actual database fields may be different in your situation)

Answer (score 2):

To add to Calanus's answer, you can format the cell to show a percent via its Right-Click Properties or by using the FORMAT function.

```
=FORMAT((Fields!Success.Value/Fields!Total.Value), "P")
=FORMAT((Fields!NotSuccess.Value/Fields!Total.Vlaue), "P")
```

Comment: Or you can highlight the cell in the designer and add a "p" in the Format property in the Properties window.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a matrix then you can use the group to divide by either column or row, i.e.,

```
=round((Fields!count.Value/sum(Fields!count.Value,"matrix1_RowGroup1") * 100,2) & " %"
```

the field count would be the total of any given category

Example of record set

```
CAMPAIGN COUNT TYPE
Campaing1 1 Success
Campaing1 4 Not Success
Campaing2 4 Success
Campaing2 4 Not Success
```